# How to parse response from custom connector

Tags: azure-active-directory, swagger, powerapps, connector

I have an action call on my custom connector that returns JSON with data:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(mail,displayName,department)/$entity",
  "mail": "mail@company.com",
  "displayName": "First Last",
  "department": "DPE-DES-Platform Services"
}
```

I want to parse this response and store 'department' into a variable that I can use for another action call as a parameter. How would I do this? Sorry if this is elementary, I'm very new to PowerApps.

I have like 10 calls I need to make with graph API and I only want to display the end result, so I need some way to store information into variables. If there was some way I could interact with the information through code that would be great, because I also need to do things like create data structures and modify variables if possible

Comment: Need to see your custom connector call. Redact any sensitive info of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to directly parse the JSON response in Powerapps . You can use Powerapps with Power automate to parse the JSON response by using Action `“Parse JSON”`.

**Reference:** [Solved: Parse JSON string in Power APPS - Power Platform Community (microsoft.com)](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Parse-JSON-string-in-Power-APPS/td-p/381832)

**For the feature you can also upvote the feature request here** :
[Parse JSON in PowerApps - Power Platform Community (microsoft.com)](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/Parse-JSON-in-PowerApps/idi-p/359563)

**For more details on Powerapps :** [Microsoft Power Apps documentation - Power Apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/)

Answer (score 0):

You might try using dot (`.`) notation on the end of your Custom Connector call. Depending on the shape of the actual response, you can parse out a value that way.

**Something like:**

```
Set(varDept, 
    ccCall.GetDept({whatever:criteria}).department
)
```